# How to join on a list using JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

Lets say you have two Entities Cats and Licks. Each has a list of the other. How do you write JPA to find one, given the id of the other.

My question is this: why not make this more simple? This interface is confusing... but here is how you do it anyway.

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Test
public void testFindCatsByLickId() throws Exception
{
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

    Root<Cat> cats = cq.from( Cat.class );
    Root<Lick> licks = cq.from( Lick.class );
    ListJoin<Cat, Lick> joinCatL = cats.join(Cat_.lickList);

   // just creating the following ListJoin object will cause this query to fail!
   // ListJoin<Lick, Cat> joinLCat = lick.join(Lick_.catList);

    Predicate p = cb.and(  
                           cb.equal(licks.get(Lick_.lickId), new Integer(2))
                         , cb.equal(licks, joinCatL)
                        );

    cq.select(cats).where(p);

 TypedQuery query = em.createQuery(cq);

    List<Cat> list = query.getResultList();

    assertList( list );
    assertTrue(null != list && ! list.isEmpty() );
}
```

Comment: wait are you asking a question or answering your own?  I am confused as to what this is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

The criteria API is useful when you need to dynamically compose a query from a set of optional search criteria. In this case, using JPQL leads to much simpler and more readable code:

```
String jpql = "select cat from Lick lick inner joinlick.cats cat where lick.id = :lickId";
List<Cat> cats = em.createQuery(jpql, Cat.class).setParameter("lickId", 2)
                   .getResultList();
```

Or even simpler, without any query at all:

```
Lick lick = em.get(Lick.class, 2);
List<Cat> cats = lick.getCats();
```

Comment: The problem is late binding, and not knowing what parts of the query you might or might not need. When that starts happening, and it always does, you need the criteria API. I found it difficult to find out how to set up queries like the one above. When I finally figured it out, I decided to make sure it was here to find for others. So, no, there, isn't really a question...but there is a lot of frustration.